# Catch an exception raised by a child process in a parent process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to catch an Exception raised by a child process, and have been running into some issues. The gist of my code is:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
  def __init__(self, msg):
    self.msg = msg

  def __str__(self):
    return self.msg    

def update(partition):
  if os.getpid() % 2 == 0:
    raise CustomException('PID was divisible by 2!')
  else:
    # Do something fancy

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    some_response = get_response_from_another_method()
    partition_size = 100
    p = Pool(config.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES)
    for i in range(0, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
      partition = get_partition(some_response, partition_size)
      x = p.apply_async(update, args=(partition,))
    x.get()
    p.close()
    p.join()
  except CustomException as e:
    log.error('There was an error')
    if email_notifier.send_notification(e.msg):
      log.debug('Email notification sent')
    else:
      log.error('An error occurred while sending an email.')
```

When I run this, I am seeing:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 259, in _handle_results
    task = get()
TypeError: ('__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)', <class 'CustomException'>, ())
```

Is there some facility to do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In short, this is something of a quirk in Python 2, and a related issue is referenced in this [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue9400). It has to do with how exceptions are pickled. The simplest solution is perhaps to alter `CustomException` so that it calls its parent class initializer. Alternatively, if you're able, I'd suggest moving to Python 3.

For example, this code works fine in both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class CustomException(Exception):
    pass

def foo():
    raise CustomException('PID was divisible by 2!')

pool = Pool()
result = pool.apply_async(foo, [])
```

But if we alter `CustomException` so that it has a required argument:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, required):
        self.required = required
```

The above example results in a `TypeError` being raised under Python 2. It works under Python 3.

The problem is that `CustomException` inherits `Exception`'s `__reduce__` method, which tells Python how to pickle an instance. The inherited `__reduce__` knows nothing about `CustomException`'s call signature, so unpickling isn't done correctly.

A quick fix is to simply call the parent class's `__init__`:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        super(Exception, self).__init__()
        self.msg = msg
```

But since you really aren't doing anything special with the message, why not just define:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass
```